Exercise 1.7 of Atiyah and Macdonald

Let $A$ be a ring in which every element $x$ satisfies $x^n = x$ for some $n\gt 1$ (depending on $x$). Show that every prime ideal in $A$ is maximal.

Let $N$ and $J$ be nilradical and Jacobson radical of $A$, respectively. In this solution book, it is shown that (page number 8) $$\bigcap \{ \text{prime ideals of }A\} =N=J=\bigcap \{ \text{maximal ideals of }A \} \implies \{ \text{prime ideals of }A \} = \{ \text{maximal ideals of }A \}.$$
I don’t see directly why this implication holds.

It is certainly not true that equality between the Jacobson radical and nilradical implies every prime ideal is maximal. For example, the Jacobson radical equals the nilradical equals $0$ in all polynomial rings over fields, but the $0$ ideal is prime but not maximal in such rings.

Yeah don't trust what you read on the internet. Greetings from the moon!

I guess the question should be retitled so that it's not a duplicate of this and this and probably a few other questions.

I trust rschwieb's legwork on this enough to dupehammer it. Originally may be it wasn't a duplicate, but the answers make it so.

@rschwieb my intention for the title was whosoever looking for solution of this exercise will find this incorrect proof, without making it hard to find/search. Anyway, how about “Alternative proof of exercise 1.7…” or “Incorrect proof of exercise 1.7…” title? Certainly this post is not duplicate of linked posts.

@MartinBrandenburg Good thing the abstract to this internet source is even "This note is based on my practice about Atiyah-MacDonald’s book [3]. There may be a lot of errors on it. Use it at your own risk." :)

@user264745 I was afraid so. Such a question might fare better next time if it led with "This proof appears here <...> but I think that this following bit doesn't follow from this other bit for the following reasons <...>. Can someone clarify whether this is valid?"   The way this post was written it looks like people took license to just hand you an answer without regards to your interest in the proposed solution.

@user264745: I've edited my answer to address the solution given in the solution book (which, to be honest, looks pretty hopeless, I am sorry to say). I see why someone would want to mark this question as a duplicate; having all of these posts associated with each other helps with site organisation.

As mentioned in the comments, the solution given in the book is not correct. Let me reproduce it here:

Let $J$ be the Jacobson radical and $\mathfrak R$ be nilradical. Suppose $J\supsetneq\mathfrak R$. Then, it contains $x\in J\setminus\mathfrak R$ such that $x^n=x$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Now $x(1 − x^{n−1}) = 0$, and $1 − x^{n−1}$ has a form $1 + xy$ for some $y = −x^{n−1} \in A$, thus $1-x^{n-1}$ is a unit in $A$ by Proposition 1.9. Hence, $x=0$, contradiction. This implies $J=\mathfrak R$. It implies all prime ideals are maximal, otherwise $J\neq\mathfrak R$.

Everything up to the last sentence is correct, save for few typos. First, the clause "$x^n=x$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$" should instead be "$x^n=x$ for some integer $n>1$". Second, it should say "$1-x^{n-1}$" has the form $1-xy$, where $y=x^{n-2}$". Proposition 1.9 tells us that for all (commutative) rings $A$, and $x\in A$,
$$
x\in J\iff\forall y\in A(\text{$1-xy$ is a unit)} \, .
$$
Thus, the argument used to conclude that $J=\mathfrak R$ is fine.
However, showing that the nilradical and Jacobson radical coincide is not enough to conclude that every prime ideal is maximal. Indeed, as Alex Kruckman points out in the comments, if $k$ is a field, then the Jacoboson radical and nilradical of $k[x]$ both equal $(0)$ (the easiest way to show that the Jacobson radical equals $(0)$ is to appeal to Proposition 1.9). On the other hand, $(0)$ is prime (since $k[x]$ is an integral domain), but $(0)$ is not maximal (since $k[x]$ is not a field).
There are also a number of elementary arguments to establish the claim that you want, as mentioned in Rob Arthan's answer. Here is an alternative to what he suggested. Suppose $\mathfrak a\subset A$ is a prime ideal, and $x\not\in\mathfrak a$. It suffices to show that $\mathfrak a+(x)=(1)$. Let $n>1$ be an integer such that $x^n=x$. Then,
$$x^n-x=x(x^{n-1}-1)=0\in\mathfrak a \, ,$$
hence $x^{n-1}-1\in\mathfrak a$, and the result follows.

Thank you so much for an alternative approach.

@user264745: No problem! I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you have any questions.

I really like the edit. I suppose, author of solution book meant to write $y=-x^{n-2}\in A$. Then $1-x^{n-1}$ is unit, no? Jacobson radical of $k[x]$ equal $(0)$ follows from proposition 1.9 and the units in $k[x]$ are precisely non zero constant polynomial.

I don't see how to make the answer you got from the solution book work, but the question has a more elementary answer that I suspect is the one Atiyah and Macdonald expected you to give:
Let $I$ be a prime ideal of $A$ and consider the ring $A/I$. Let $x$ be a non-zero element of $A/I$. Then for some $n > 1$, $x^n = x$ (do you see why?) and then $x(x^{n-1} - 1) = 0$. As $I$ is a prime ideal, $A/I$ is an integral domain, so this implies that either $x = 0$ or $x^{n-1} - 1 = 0$. However, $x \neq 0$ by assumption, so we must have $x^{n-1} - 1 = 0$, i.e., $x(x^{n-2}) = 1$. So $x$ is invertible with inverse $x^{n-2}$. We have shown that every non-zero element of $A/I$ is invertible, i.e., that $A/I$ is a field. This implies that $I$ is maximal.

This isn't really different from this solution or this solution. It's fine to make a case that a solution could be used to disprove the user's suggested approach, but really what is the point of duplicating content we already have?
